# Create searcher to Dataview in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In the dataview component i can insert a dataitem, but how i do insert a searcher?,  as in the list component

Comment: what do you mean by `searcher`?

Comment: Something like this: [Example Search List](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/list-search/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataviews and Lists are directly bound to Stores (`Ext.data.Store`). Therefore, anything that happens to that store will be reflected in the view.

So what you need to do is **filter** the store. You can do this by using the `filter` or `filterBy` methods on store.

More information: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter

**Example**

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['text'],
    data: [
        { text: 'one'},
        { text: 'two'},
        { text: 'three'}
    ]
});

store.filter('text', 'one'); // will only show the one record
```